# access QWebPage object from WebView QML element

Tags: c++, qt4, qml, qtwebkit, qwebview

Is there a way to access the `QWebPage` object from `WebView`'s underlying `QWebView` object?

`QWebView` has:

```
QWebPage * QWebView::page () const
```

src: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#page

However it doesn't seem to be exposed in QML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tryed it, but ...

In [`qdeclarativewebview_p.h` at line 59](http://gitorious.org/+qtwebkit-developers/webkit/qtwebkit/blobs/859cec272295fdecc86cf1cbe9c3e891070cc682/WebKit/qt/declarative/qdeclarativewebview_p.h#line159) there is defined as *public*:

```
159  QWebPage *page() const;
160  void setPage(QWebPage *page);
```

So you should be able to access this at least from C++ (but not directly from QML).

If you need it in QML, you can inherit the original `QDeclarativeWebView` and expose this property for access in QML.

Comment: that's what I figured. Pity it's not enabled by default.